# how to use subqueries to COUNT() and SUM() items

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to get a list of:

```
StockPart.title   |   QtyAvailable   |   SumOfItemsCost
StockPart.title   |   QtyAvailable   |   SumOfItemsCost
StockPart.title   |   QtyAvailable   |   SumOfItemsCost
StockPart.title   |   QtyAvailable   |   SumOfItemsCost
```

Trying to explain:

- **StockPart.title** comes from stock_parts table
- **QtyAvailable** is the count() of `stock_items` of that StockPart `(stock_items.status = NULL && stock_items.stock_part_id = stock_part.id)`
- **SumOfItemsCost** is `QtyAvailable * shipments.item_cost`

My table structure is

```
stock_parts
  - id
  - title

stock_items
  - id
  - stock_part_id
  - shipment_id

shipments
  - item_cost
```

So i'm a bit lost on how to do this. I'm trying things like this:

```
SELECT
  stock_parts.id,
  stock_parts.title,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock_items WHERE
                    stock_items.stock_part_id = stock_parts.id
                    AND stock_items.status = NULL)
                    AS qty_available
FROM
  stock_parts,
  stock_items
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you could be doing:

```
SELECT
    stock_parts.title,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM stock_items 
        WHERE stock_items.id = stckItm.id
    ),
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(item_cost) 
        FROM stock_items 
        INNER JOIN shipments ON shipments.id = stock_items.shipment_id 
        WHERE stock_items.id = stckItm.id
    )
FROM
    stock_items stckItm
inner join
    stock_parts
ON
    stckItm.stock_part_id = stock_parts.id
```

Comment: Almost there. This is showing a list of `stock_items`. I need it grouped by `stock_items.stock_part_id` counting the sub-queries you did.

Comment: I mean... the subquery should be something like `COUNT(*) stock_items WHERE stock_items.stock_part_id = stock_parts.id`

Comment: Great, i have added another answer when you have the result table grouped by the StockPart

Answer (score 2):

if you want it grouped:

```
SELECT
    stock_parts.title,
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(shipments.item_cost) 
FROM
    stock_items
INNER JOIN
    stock_parts
ON
    stock_items.stock_part_id = stock_parts.id
INNER JOIN
    shipments
ON
    shipments.id = stock_items.shipment_id
GROUP BY stock_parts.id
```